# Docker image based on smaller base image is heavier

Tags: docker, nvidia, images

I'm creating two docker images, one for development and another one for production. These images are based on the same base image (provided by NVIDIA) with the difference that one is the development one and the other one is the runtime one (the latter is smaller).

Just to illustrate what I'm doing, is something like this:

- **Dockerfile**:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental
ARG MODE
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.8.0-cudnn8-${MODE}-ubuntu22.04 AS base

...
```

Then I just run:  `docker build -f ./Dockerfile --build-arg MODE="devel" .`

After only changing the base image (devel vs. runtime), it turns out that the runtime/production Docker image is greater in size than the development one (please, remember that the base image of the development one is greater originally).

Inspecting the layers and commands of the Dockerfile (`docker history --no-trunc --format "{{.CreatedBy}}: {{.Size}}" $IMAGE_ID`) the layers/commands are the same and the size of them is the same.

What could be the reason for the difference of size between the two images?

Comment: I read to “only changing the base image”, and asked my self what was the other bit? The question is not clear. Please proof read, do not leave stuff out. If you docker file is very big, then create a minimal one that excipients the problem (When I do this 90% of the time I answer my own question. Don't forget to add an answer if you do figure it out). Also show output of commands (don't just describe). If you don't figure it out on your own, then the clearer question will help us to do it.